# User \"system:anonymous\" cannot create resource \"pods\" using kubernetes api

Tags: kubernetes

Using kubernetes api

`https://${MASTERSERVER}:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods --insecure` 
to create a pod

Getting this error on creation:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "pods is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot create resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "pods"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

How do I add the auth info?

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#without-kubectl-proxy) you need to pass an authentication bearer token using `Authorization` header like below

```
# Gets the token value
TOKEN=$(kubectl get secrets -o jsonpath="{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations['kubernetes\.io/service-account\.name']=='default')].data.token}"|base64 --decode)

# Explore the API with TOKEN
curl -X GET $APISERVER/api --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
```

The output is similar to this:

```
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "10.0.1.149:443"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: this works for $APISERVER/api but not for other POST; like ns/default/pods